# select the third element in every parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help. How do I select the `<p>` elements in every `<div>` on the page (for adding some class) beginning from the third `<p>` element?

I've tried to select like -   `$('div p').slice(1).addClass('hidden');`
but in result only one `<p>` element remains on the page

Comment: what does your html look like?  Do you have a <div> with a bunch of <p>'s?

Comment: http://codepen.io/DanPol/pen/pEEkaW?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do this *without* javascript....

```css
.thirds p:nth-child(3n) { background: red; color: #fff; }
.threeplus p:nth-child(n+3) { background: green; color: #fff; }


div { 
  margin: 20px 0; 
  background: #eee; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;}
p { margin: 0 0 2px; padding:0; }
```

```html
<div class="thirds">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="threeplus">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>
```

To hide 3rd and following paragraph in *any* div, just generalize the CSS:

```css
div p:nth-child(n+3) {  display: none; }


div { 
  margin: 20px 0; 
  background: #eee; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;}
p { margin: 0 0 2px; padding:0; }
```

```html
<div class="thirds">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="threeplus">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="thirds">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="threeplus">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="thirds">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="anotherClass">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="anotherRandomClass" id="andanID">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>

<div class="moreClass">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>Six</p>
  <p>Seven</p>
  <p>Eight</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes, but I need to hide all P elements in the ALL DIV beginning from third with one function, and not to search P in every Div with different classes. Something like $('div p').slice(2) - searches  elements but not in all div but only in the first.   http://codepen.io/DanPol/pen/pEEkaW

Comment: You can generalize the CSS a great deal... `div p:nth-child(n+3) { display: none; } ` will hide *every* third and following paragraph in *any* div. @DimaPoliuliuk see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$('div p:gt(1)').addClass('hidden');
```

The index for `:gt()` is zero-based, so the above will select the third and higher.

Comment: and if I have several DIVs, how can I go throw all DIVs and get P element in every one beggining from third..?